# Disable fullPage Scroll below specified resolution

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming, fullpage.js

I am using fullPage.js(js plugin provide one page scroll functionality), Now I have to disable this below 1199 width. I tried to achieve this by calling it's function inside both , widow load and resize, on a condition based (that window width should be greater then 1199), It works on window load but resize function is not working and it shows error in console

> Error::
>   fullPage: Fullpage.js can only be initialized once and you are doing
>   it multiple times!

Because library load two times once in page load and another time on window resize. How can I disable this below width 1199 on both window resize and window load.

This is my code:

```
    var init = {
    one_page_scroll : function(){ 
                /*--------- one pge scroll --------*/
                var windowWidth = $(window).width();
                if(windowWidth > 1199){
                    $('#fullpage').children().each(function(){
                        $(this).not( ".vc_row-full-width" ).addClass('section');
                    });
                    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                        navigation: true,
                        interlockedSlides: false,
                        fixedElements : '',
                    });

                }

            },
};
```

And I called this function inside both, on window load and window resize , as mentioned below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('load', function(){
        init.one_page_scroll();
    });
});
jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(windowWidth > 1199){ 
        init.one_page_scroll();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make use of the responsive options instead of not initialising it?

You can use `responsiveWidth` or `responsiveHeight` that will turn off autoScrolling. Then you can combine it with `fp-auto-height-responsive` that will turn off fullscreen sections and slides.

And if you even need more, you can make use of the `responsiveSlides` option to turn horizontal slides into vertical ones on responsive.